# I type in ls or anything in the ftp command line I enter in "passive mode" and then can not do anything

Tags: linux, webserver, vsftpd, file-server

I have a `vsftpd`  server running.
Whenever I type in `ls` or anything in the `ftp` command line I enter in "passive mode" and then can not do anything.

I need to have a working `ftp` so I can transfer files. Of course, I can just do it with `fileZile`, but there I can transfer from my machine to my pc but not vice versa.

If you do not understand my question I can always reask it in a different way.

[image]

Comment: Could you start again with the passive mode before the `ls` command. 

The FTP protocol is known to be troublesome with NAT, firewall… other protocols are preferred if available (sftp, scp…)

Comment: hi DJB, do you know if you had any firewall and/or NAT between your PC and your vsftpd server ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please consider rephrasing your question. At the moment it is not clear whether the problem only occurs when you type `ls` while in passive mode already, or if typing `ls` automatically switches you to passive mode and then you can't do anything. Also, please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Hey thanks. Trying to answer all questions. FIrst I enter ftp -p [IP] then my username and password. Once in I type p.example ls and enter passive mode directly. Then I get the following message. {227 Entering passive mode [IP]}.  I would need to maybe transfer files or manage files there.  Sorry about the screenshot did not know. I do have a firewall but the vsftpd server is running on a VM on my pc. (School exam project). I am using vsftpd.  Hope this answers everything

Comment: Hey just wanted to come back. I now manage to do the connection per sftp  but only able to log in with my main user, and not with my admin users haha